# SQL, between operator but using only one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I want, with a single SQL query, check if number (eg. 12, 20) is in range, eg. 1-20.

Live example:
I have table `rules`:

```
ID  name    range
1   rule_1  1-20
2   rule_2  21-50
```

etc.

Each GET /rule request will generate random number (from range 1 - 100), then I need to get rules which range value covers that number.

How with SQL query get rule which range definition covers given number, for example for number = 5 it should return `rule_1`, for number = 40 it should return `rule_2` etc etc.

The query should work in PostgreSQL and SQLite.

Comment: And you cannot redesign your table to have two columns, like range_min and range_max?

Comment: It would be quite easy with Postgres, but that wouldn't work in SQLite. But you should really fix this broken data model

Answer (score 3):

Postgresql and SQLite have string functions needed to parse a string and convert it to a number, but they are different in syntax.
For SQLite:

```
select *
from rules
where ? between 
  range + 0
  and
  substr(range, instr(range, '-') + 1) + 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a3XyXzR4wFEcpAgcqB6kde/0).
For Postgresql:

```
select *
from rules
where ? between 
  substring(range, 1, position('-' in range) - 1)::int
  and
  substring(range, position('-' in range) + 1)::int
```

I used `substring()` function here just because it works also in SQLite, although there is also [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) in Postgresql.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Qcmr6A8zAYUsPmhqJ4xz6/1).

Answer (score 1):

Fix your rules so the `range` is two columns:

```
ID  name    range_lo    range_hi
1   rule_1  1           20
2   rule_2  21          50
```

Then you can simply do:

```
select r.*
from ranges r
where ? >= range_lo and ? <= range_hi;
```

If you want the ranges to be non-overlapping with no gaps, you could also use:

```
ID  name    range_start
1   rule_1  1
2   rule_2  21
```

And then:

```
select r.*
from ranges r
where ? >= range_start
order by range_start desc
limit 1;
```

Under no circumstances should you be storing numeric ranges as strings.

Comment: I can not do that. I need to work with that table and I'm not allowed to change table definition

Comment: You should put your efforts into fixing the table.  It is broken.  Further, it appears to be broken in two databases, which rises to the absurd.